# DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have tried this query :

```
var a  = (from q in dtRe
          from p in q.Pro
          where motsE.All(word => p.Title.Contains(word))
          select q);
```

But I have an error :

> DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Nom du paramètre : input

Note that dtResult of type `IQueryable<uio>` and p is of type `ICollection<prop>`and this an array of strings `motsCt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error because i'am passing `wordE` that is words with , char , i have change it with `wordEtSp` and it works !

Answer (score 0):

try adding `.ToList()`

```
var a  = (from q in dtRe.ToList()
      from p in q.Pro
      where WordEt.All(word => p.Title.Contains(word))
      select q);
```

Comment: when i add ToList() it takes munch time because i have 239.000 records in dtResult , and the result of query count = 0;

Comment: how about `dtResult.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: yes it works but count = 0 and i need to do asquerable in the end because i need a variable asquerable after my algorithm